# How to stop form from being re-submitted from particular url again

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a path `http://www.example.com/confirm_post/12`, which submits a post request to `posts#confirm_post`. When a user successfully submits a form from that path, is there a way to stop the user from visiting the same path again (it could be from the browser back button or the user hitting the url manually)?

Comment: I don't know what you want to do, but I will manage `confirm_post` in back-end.

In `http://www.example.com/confirm_post/12` , I will check if post **12** is confirm. If not, post request, else, redirect on another page. Hope this help !

Comment: You can't stop a user from requesting a path, but you can send back an error status, redirect, etc.

Comment: You first say _"path [...] which submits a post"_ and then _"user [...] submits a form"_. So which action does result in a POST request, visiting the URL or submitting a form? And what do you want to prevent, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

> When a user successfully submits a form from that path, is there a way
>   to stop the user from visiting the same path again (it could be from
>   the browser back button or the user hitting the url manually)?

The browser does not treat POST and GET requests equally. POST requests are non-idempotent so the browser will in most cases actually warn you if you try to back up.

However you can't actually prevent the browser from resending any request but this usually handled by just adding a simple conditional in the controller or a model validation such as a uniqueness validation. Your controller must be able to handle repeated or unauthorized requests and return a response without unintended side effects.

In this case I would handle it like so:

```
resources :posts do
  patch :confirm
end
```

---

```
      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                       Controller#Action
post_confirm PATCH  /posts/:post_id/confirm(.:format) posts#confirm
...
```

---

```
# on the edit or show view
<% unless @post.confirmed? %>
  <%= button_to("Confirm", post_confirm_path(@post), method: :patch) %>
<% end %>
```

---

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  # PATCH /posts/:post_id
  def confirm
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    if @post.confirmed?
      # we return since we want to bail early
      redirect_to @post, error: "Post already confirmed." and return
    end
    if @post.update(confirmed: true) 
      redirect_to @post, success: "Post confirmed." 
    else
      redirect_to @post, error: "Post could not be confirmed"
    end 
  end
  # ...
end
```

Note that this uses the `PATCH` HTTP verb instead of `POST` since we are updating a resource - not creating a new resource.